# Trying to post an image to a bot, however it gets posted multiple times. Unable to figure out where the loop is occuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

I have created a bot that posts image whenever you type anything after mentioning the bot's name. However, the bot should post the image only once but it keeps posting multiple time. Would really appreciate any help in figuring out the solution for this flaw

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Bot = require('slackbots');
var http = require('http');
var SethuBot = function Constructor(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
    this.settings.name = this.settings.name || 'mufc';
    this.user = null;
};

util.inherits(SethuBot, Bot);

SethuBot.prototype.run = function() {
    SethuBot.super_.call(this, this.settings);
    this.on('start', this._onStart);
    this.on('message', this._onMessage);
};

SethuBot.prototype._onStart = function() {
    this._loadBotUser();
};

SethuBot.prototype._onMessage = function(message) {
    if (this._isChatMessage(message) && !this._isFromSethuBot(message)) {
        this._smartresponse(message);
    }
};

SethuBot.prototype._smartresponse = function(originalMessage) {
    var self = this;
    var channel = self._getChannelById(originalMessage.channel);
    var urlToQuery = '';
    var firstName = '';

    var a = 'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03481/David_Beckham_3481418k.jpg';

    self.postMessageToChannel(channel.name, a, {
        as_user: true,
        attachments: [{
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of theattachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "image_url": a
                // "ts": 1
        }]
    });
};
SethuBot.prototype._loadBotUser = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.user = this.users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.name === self.name;
    })[0];
};

SethuBot.prototype._isChatMessage = function(message) {
    return message.type === 'message' && Boolean(message.text);
};

SethuBot.prototype._isChannelConversation = function(message) {
    return typeof message.channel === 'string' &&
        message.channel[0] === 'C';
};

SethuBot.prototype._isFromSethuBot = function(message) {
    return message.user === this.user.id;
};

SethuBot.prototype._getChannelById = function(channelId) {
    return this.channels.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id === channelId;
    })[0];
};

module.exports = SethuBot;
```

Comment: What kind of output do you see if you `console.log(message)` in `_onMessage`? I'm wondering if there's other message subtype events being thrown around when your bot posts...